# Odd browser compatibility issue with IE 6/7/8 browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

thanks in advance for your help. I'm working on this site and have an odd problem with jquery-twit and IE 6/7/8.

If you take a look at any other page than the homepage in an IE browser of any stripe the twitter feed button and contact form button appear at the top of the page, I'm at a loss to explain it - it works on the homepage, all the files appear to be loading correctly etc.

The pages outside the homepage also do not centre in IE as they should, I'm currently unsure if this is down to the jquery problem or a separate issue.

Any pointers debugging these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the comment `<!-- page start -->` before your doctype. The doctype **must** be the first line of your HTML, otherwise IE will trigger Quirks mode. Your homepage is fine, this is why the other pages break.

Comment: Well, that's a fairly big DOH!! moment for me isn't it. Thank you very much for your help, massively appreciated.